# Laravel query not executed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My query in my view is not executed. from the `->select('name')` it just displays like a plain text on my website.

```
    <tbody>
    @foreach($getdeaths as $getdeath)
    <tr>
        <? DB::table('players')->select('name')->where('id', $getdeath->player_id)->get(); ?>
        <td>{{ $getdeath->player_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $getdeath->level }}</td>
        <td>{{ date("d F Y (H:i)", strtotime($getdeath->time)) }}</td>
        <td>@if($getdeath->is_player == 1)
            {{ '<a href="characters/'.$getdeath->killed_by.'">'.$getdeath->killed_by.'</a> (PVP)' }}
            @else
            {{ $getdeath->killed_by }}
            @endif</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: what is the DB::table() trying to do? display the result? or save the variable?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Exchange I need it to execute a query like this: `SELECT name FROM players WHERE id = $getdeath->player_id`  Never really used Query Builder.

Comment: and do what with the result? display it? use it elsewhere? show the name?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange show the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<? DB::table('players')->select('name')->where('id', $getdeath->player_id)->get(); ?>
```

to

```
<?= DB::table('players')->where('id', $getdeath->player_id)->pluck('name'); ?>
```

`<?` means `php`

`<?=` means `php echo`

You could save the var and echo it like normal:

```
{{ $x=DB::table('players')->where('id', $getdeath->player_id)->pluck('name'); }}
{{ $x }}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's probably working, but it's displaying `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

Comment: thanks, works. How could I put it in a variable and echo it in my first td? Do I have to keep the php code tag open?

Comment: i changed the answer again - look at the last example